# How to Mock Integers in Scala

Tags: scala, integer, tdd

The aim is to mock a function which generates Random Integers in Scala. The error `value is not a member of int` occurs while the function returns an integer.

**Test:**

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito._

class NumberSequencesTests extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with MockitoSugar {
  test("randomInteger") {
    when(NumberSequences.numbersequence(5).thenReturn(5))
  }
}
```

**Main:**

```
object NumberSequences {
  def randomInteger(a: Int) : Int = {
    scala.util.Random.nextInt(a) + 1
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[error] C:\scala\numbersequences\scala\NumberSequencesTest.scala:20: value the
nReturn is not a member of Int
[error]         when(NumberSequences.numbersequence(5).thenReturn(5))
[error]                                                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 29, 2014 11:19:30 PM
```

Comment: isn't that `when(NumberSequences.numberSequences(5)).thenReturn(5)` (not the same parentheses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
when(NumberSequences.numbersequence(5).thenReturn(5))
```

with

```
when(NumberSequences.numbersequence(5)).thenReturn(5)
```